# .bat file for renaming another file without giving the path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder that cointains a .bat file and another folder called Config.

I can't figure out how to rename a file (test.txt) in the folder Config without giving the path to the file.

I want the .bat file to automatically get the parent folder, then go into the Config folder and rename the test.txt into something else.

This is what I've already found to rename a file

```
ren C:\Users\Admin\Directory\Config\test.txt something.txt
```

And I guess that what I want should look like this but I can't figure out how.

```
ren %ConfigDirectory%\test.txt something.txt
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: In what folder your .bat file is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
set parentdir=%cd%
ren %parentdir%\test.txt something.txt
```

The current directory is stored in the variable %cd%, you could use one line (`ren %cd%\test.txt something.txt`), but using these two always works.
And if you want to add a directory to the path:

```
set parentdir=%cd%
set dir=%parentdir%\directory
ren %dir%\test.txt something.txt
```

EDIT: apparently quotations around the directory helps the command work out:

```
set parentdir=%cd%
ren "%parentdir%\test.txt" something.txt
```

Comment: Adding quotations did exactly what I wanted. The last line looks like this now, maybe you can edit your first post. ren "%dir%\test.txt" something.txt

Answer (score 1):

this isn't answer, but i can't commenting on this amazing forum.. huh *a nice rule*

and where are your .bat file?.. his path is..

this path `C:\Users\Admin\Directory\Config` isn't default path for os windows.. so no one variable, in environment, haven't this value.. and you can't use such variable until you append her:

`setx ConfigDirectory C:\Users\Admin\Directory\Config`

maximum what you can do until.. `%userprofile%\Directory\Config\test.txt`

also you can point path until parent dir of the batch file

`%~dp0`

so if your .bat file is in `C:\Users\Admin\Directory` that path, until test.txt, will be `%~dp0\config`

Comment: Okay, I know that something like %~dp0\config should do the job, but when I use this:     ren %~dp0\config\testt.txt something.txt 
I get this error: The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: I also asked not to use a path, but let the file search for the path itself since it has to edit files within the same directory.

Comment: @LesleyPeters, i'm don't understand what you mean exactly, but may be this else will help you..
`ren ".\config\test.txt" "ttt"`